# How sort facet with selected facet value?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, facet

Trying to sort facets with selected facet

Step 1: Default facets

```
[] Apple (4)
[] Banana (3)
[] Apricot (2)
[] Aubergine(2)
[] Broccoli (1)
```

Step 2 : if i select Banana Facet

```
[] Apple (4)
[x] Banana (3)
[] Apricot (2)
[] Aubergine(2)
[] Broccoli (1)
```

Step 3 : After selecting facet banana remaining facet should come in selected facet ascending format

```
[x] Banana (3)
[] Broccoli (1)
[] Apple (4)
[] Apricot (2)
[] Aubergine(2)
```

Is this possible in **Solr**?

I am using Solr 4.4.0

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if this is something that can be done with Solr, for the search server the info, that you have selected a facet is irrelevant

Actually it looks like an **UI** issue, so you should make it in the **Solr** client or in you user interface.

Answer (score -1):

You can only sort facets by count or by index

From Solr Wiki:

**facet.sort**

This param determines the ordering of the facet field constraints.

count - sort the constraints by count (highest count first)

index - to return the constraints sorted in their index order (lexicographic by indexed term). For terms in the ascii range, this will be alphabetically sorted.

The default is count if facet.limit is greater than 0, index otherwise.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.sort